# Give Web3 a description of smartcontract function

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js

Today i tested something on Uniswap when I came across a feature of Metamask or Web3 where a specific function call can have a custom Description.

[image]

As seen in the Picture, Metamask somehow got a String which replaced the normal "Contract interaction" Title. Since this is definitely not the Name of the function, and I didn´t find anything in the documentations of both web3 and Metamask, I wonder how this works.

How can I set this custom description when calling a contract with web3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the function you're calling on a contract, by checking the first four bytes (called the method signature) of the transaction data, and the ABI of a contract. You can find a detailed explanation of transaction data [here](https://medium.com/mycrypto/why-do-we-need-transaction-data-39c922930e92).

MetaMask keeps a registry of common method signatures and their corresponding description stored in a smart contract ([0x44691B39d1a75dC4E0A0346CBB15E310e6ED1E86](https://etherscan.io/address/0x44691B39d1a75dC4E0A0346CBB15E310e6ED1E86#code)) and uses [`eth-method-registry`](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-method-registry) to check the signatures. Basically it's a simple lookup to see if the signature exists in the registry.

There's also [`ethereum-lists/4bytes`](https://github.com/ethereum-lists/4bytes) which has a large overview of common method signatures and their corresponding methods.

Comment: Wow, that was really helpful. Didn´t know that this infrastructure existed.
Thanks you very much for this detailed explanation

Comment: After digging in the code of eth-method-registry, it turns out metamask only turns camelCase into nouns. So not really much magic behind that :) @morten